# Accelerate Browser multiple file input

Tags: javascript, browser

Firstly, my problem is only client-side.

I'm working on a form which contains an field

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

But when I put many files, my browser (Firefox and Chrome) is blocked during a long time before integrate files to field form.

The time according to number of file I choosen :

- 100 files : 35 seconds
- 2300 files : 15 minutes

Do you have any ideas to accelerate this process ?

Comment: Apart from buying a more powerful computer I doubt there is anything you can do about it

Comment: I use a 3Ghz Dual Core processor and I have 6GB of RAM

Comment: There are no way to divide this treatment in Javascript, with Webworkers or anything else ?

Comment: I think a web app is a wrong solution if you need to deal with that many files.

Comment: What exactly are you *doing* with the files? Where's the code?

Comment: I analyze them to update database. Thank you for these response. That's what I thought, I must program it in server-side with file in local memory. Thank you